# connect sql as dba

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning oracle sql. I downloaded sql command line on my laptop. I have an oracle account. I used `connect username/password;` to connect to sql first, it failed (I did some searches on google, someone says it might be something wrong with my username or password, because it has special character (e.g. @) in it). Then I tried `connect sys/root as sysdba;`, it worked.

After connecting to the server, I started putting my sql schemas in and populated them. Everything works fine.

My problem is when I tried to use the data I have already populated the next day they are all gone but the table still remains. How could I store my data when I close the software?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** create regular tables as `SYS`. Never. Create a regular user first, then use _that_ user for all your normal data. The `SYS` user is only intended for DBA work. Do ***NOT*** use it for anything else.

Comment: thank you. I will look for the method to create a regular user online. thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the COMMIT statement to end your current transaction and make permanent all changes performed in the transaction. See [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same struggle as me:

1. Don't connect to SQL as dba (connect as a normal user).
2. This link guides you on how to connect to SQL as a normal user [How to create a user in Oracle and grant permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447492/how-to-create-a-user-in-oracle-11g-and-grant-permissions)

Comment: Here is oracle docs for creating user [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503)