# How to lock down sql developer to allow SELECT queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there a way to lock down all tables in sql developer to allow users to only perform select queries?
I don't want users to accidentally update tables or delete tables. This question specifically applies to sql developer environment only.

Answer (score 3):

The only real way to achieve this is to create users which only have SELECT or READ privileges on the desired tables

```
Grant select on schema.table to userX;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer is just an interface that enables you to communicate with your database. Users grants, such as updates, deletes and so on must be dealt in the database itself where you can define exactly what operations each user is allowed to perform. There's plenty of information out there on how to grant access to users in Oracle.
This post might help you to get on the right track.

[How to create a user in Oracle 11g and grant permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447492/how-to-create-a-user-in-oracle-11g-and-grant-permissions)