# Creating schema for oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, schema

[image]I have download the oracle sql developer version 21.2.1 and I want to create a new connection. But I do not have any schema created. Can somebody help me or any links would be helpful.

Note: I have searched on youtube and google. All the tutorials that I have seen seems to have already a schema.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a user in Oracle 11g and grant permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447492/how-to-create-a-user-in-oracle-11g-and-grant-permissions)

Comment: In Oracle "Schema" and "User" are synonyms.

Comment: Have you installed the oracle database itself, or have access to an oracle database? (developer is just a development environment, it doesn't include the database server software)

Answer (score 1):

Well, SQL Developer you downloaded is just a **tool** you'd use to access an Oracle database. What you need next is the database itself. Once you download & install it, create user (schema). This is 11g database version example:

Connect as a privileged user (SYS if you don't have any other; and you probably don't) using SQL*Plus (command-line tool):

```
SQL> connect sys/password_goes_here@xe as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;

TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USER_DATA
```

Create user:

```
SQL> create user will identified by ashoti
  2  default tablespace user_data
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on user_data;

User created.
```

Grant privileges which will allow that user to actually do something:

```
SQL> grant create session to will;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create table to will;

Grant succeeded.
```

That's it; connect as newly created user:

```
SQL> connect will/ashoti@xe
Connected.
SQL> create table test as select sysdate as datum from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;

DATUM
----------
06.10.2021

SQL>
```

It *works*; moreover, it means that you should now be able to establish connection via SQL Developer as well.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, thank you for your help. I was looking to the database server and I have find this one Oracle Solaris (x86 systems, 64-bit) this is the right one I think.

Comment: I don't know; you should pick the one that suits operating system you have. If you - for example - download database which is to be installed on Linux and your computer runs Microsoft Windows, it certainly won't work.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, this is the link where I can download the database https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html I have windows machine 64bit

Comment: Then you certainly wouldn't install database that runs on Solaris, would you? If it is MS Windows, I'd suggest you to download Oracle database **Express Edition** (XE); it is at the bottom of that page.