# Trying to drop column using ALTER in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
create table p_key(sr_no int,name varchar2(50),primary key(sr_no));

select * from  p_key;
insert into p_key values(1,'A');

insert into p_key values(2,'B');
alter table p_key add city varchar(22);

alter table p_key drop column city;
```

> ```
> Error starting at line : 272 in command -
> alter table p_key drop column city
> Error report -
> ORA-12988: cannot drop column from table owned by SYS
> 12988. 00000 -  "cannot drop column from table owned by SYS"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a column from a system table.
> *Action:   This action is not allowed
> ```

It works in MySQL but I want to to try in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Try to add scheme name before table name, for example if you connected as scott, try to replase table name `p_key` to `scott.p_key`

Comment: @FriendlyDragon The OP's error message states the problem is that they are connected to the `SYS` user and dropping columns from system tables is forbidden. The answer is **not** to specify the schema name, it is to not create tables in a system user and use a normal user instead.

Answer (score 1):

**NEVER** create tables in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` user. If you modify the system tables then you risk making your database unusable.

Always create a new user and work in their schema.

---

The error message tells you the problem:

> ```
> Error starting at line : 272 in command -
> alter table p_key drop column city
> Error report -
> ORA-12988: cannot drop column from table owned by SYS
> 12988. 00000 -  "cannot drop column from table owned by SYS"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a column from a system table.
> *Action:   This action is not allowed
> ```

Your query works if you are not working as a system user, so do not use a system user.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HsBDy13L)

Comment: but how modify ?
how to create a new user ?

Comment: @HarshadMehta A very quick search of the internet for "oracle create user" gives you the answer to that question. Among the many resources on the topic is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447492/how-to-create-a-user-in-oracle-11g-and-grant-permissions

Comment: ok..will try
Thank You

Comment: Error starting at line : 383 in command -
create user dummy identified by dummy
Error report-
ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
65096. 00000 -"invalid common user or role name"
*Cause: An attempt was made to create a common user or role with a name
    that was not valid for common users or roles. In addition to the
    usual rules for user and role names, common user and role names
           must consist only of ASCII characters, and must contain the prefix
           specified in common_user_prefix parameter.
*Action:   Specify a valid common user or role name.

Comment: @HarshadMehta Again, a very quick search of the internet for "ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name" gives you many solutions including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330968/error-ora-65096-invalid-common-user-or-role-name-in-oracle-database (so check you are connecting to the PDB and not the CDB).